# should I save nsuserdefaults to my custom class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I am saving user info into `NSUserDefaults` with key '**userInfo**' right now.

and when app is launched, I check if 'userInfo' exists and switch the flow.

It works very well, but is it a bad habit to directly access to `NSUserDefaults`

each time I need user's info ?

Is it better to save user info when app is launced to my custom class?

If so, can you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access NSUserDefaults when you need them. If you save the user data in your class - I assume you mean in memory - you are blocking valuable memory. Depending on the size of your user data that might be an issue. On the other hand NSUserDefaults access is fast and inexpensive.